# Issue with installation of phpMyAdmin in LAMP

Tags: lamp, phpmyadmin

I tried to install phpmyadmin on LAMP, but when trying to configure phpMyAdmin with this command:

```
include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

I got this error: `include command not found`. I got the  same result with:

```
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

Comment: i wrote /apache.conf not apache2.conf

Comment: i tried that too but same result

Answer (score 2):

ok guys i fix that with this way

just get vim editor open file with that

```
vim /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
```

and at the end of the file insert

```
# phpMyAdmin Configuration
Include /etc/phpmyadmin/apache.conf
```

and restart apache , thats it;)

http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-phpmyadmin-on-ubuntu-14-04/